# How can I tell typescript that the last argument in tuple is always a function?

Tags: typescript

I made a function that uses the spread operator to accept an overload with a various number of parameters. Unfortunately, typescript says that one of the arguments of the function is not callable. Below is an example of what I'm referring to.

```
type Arguments=[{():void}]|[string,{():void}]|[string,number,{():void}];

function overload(...args:Arguments){
  //Do stuff depending on number of arguments
  if(args.length===2)console.log(args[0]);
  if(args.length===3)console.log(args[0],args[1]);

  args[args.length-1](); //TS error here
}
//An example of how I'd like to call it
overload(()=>console.log(`I'm always the last..`));
overload('example',()=>console.log(`..and I'm a function..`));
overload('example',1,()=>console.log(`..that can be called`));
```

The last argument is always a function, because of tuples`[{():void}]|[string,{():void}]|[string,number,{():void}]`where each ends with `{():void}`.Therefore it can be called like so `args[args.length-1]();`, but I get:

> This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string
>   | number | (() => void)' are callable. Type 'string' has no call
>   signatures.ts(2349)

**My question is:** How can I tell typescript that no matter what - the last item of the shown above array is a function that I can call? Is it the best way of doing stuff like this, any suggestions on how can I achieve the same result as above in a better approach?

I've tried:

```
//NOPE
function overload(...args:Arguments):void{
  /* ... */
  if(typeof args[args.length-1]==='function'){
    args[args.length-1]();
  }
}

//NOPE
function overload(...args:[{():void}]):void;
function overload(...args:[string,{():void}]):void;
function overload(...args:[string,number,{():void}]):void;
function overload(...args:[{():void}]|[string,{():void}]|[string,number,{():void}]):void{
  /* ... */
  args[args.length-1]();
}
```

I know I can do something like this to overcome the problem:

```
function overload(...args:Arguments){
  /* ... */
  const last=args[args.length-1] as {():void};
  last();
}
```

but I call the last item of the array just once. I don't feel like making a special variable just to make this work, also that's why I write types - to get rid of errors not to create new 'fake' ones, right?. Is this `args.length-1` some sort of unknown value that TS can't deal with, but if it's so why TS assumes it's one of the 'string | number | (() => void)' types?

The code works how it was intended (written in pure javascript). Original code is a little more advanced then this, therefore, I simplified it and it seems to me it doesn't change its primary meaning. I'm using typescript 3.9.5 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the compiler to recognize that `args[args.length-1]` will return the last element of the tuple, but this is not currently supported.

The compiler understands that `args[0]` returns the *first* element, and indexing into a tuple with a [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types) will also work, but even though the compiler sees `args.length` and `1` as being of numeric literal types, the subtraction operation produces just `number`. You can't currently do math with numeric literal types; see [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) for an open suggestion to change that.  Even with this, you'd probably have trouble with a union type like `Arguments`, since the compiler would need to realize that the type of `args.length-1` is *correlated* with the type of `args`, which the compiler is also not good at.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information.

---

Somewhat more promising is the idea of having a `last()` function which takes a tuple of type `T` and returns a value of type `Last<T>` where `Last` extracts the type of the last element of the tuple.  It's not easy, because TypeScript's tuple type manipulation support currently centers around [using them in rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), so you're required to jump through hoops involving function types. There are open issues asking for more general manipulation, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#26223](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223), but nothing is part of the language yet.

Also, it's best to avoid circular conditional types (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)) so the following manipulation doesn't use them.

First I'll write `Tail<T>`, which takes a tuple `T` and returns a new tuple which is the same as `T` with its first element removed.  If `T` is `[1,2,3]`, then `Tail<T>` is `[2,3]`:

```
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((...t: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

And now `Last<T>` can be defined in terms of `Tail<T>`.  The approach is: if `T` is an array or an [open-ended tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), then just index into `T` with some very large numeric index.  Otherwise, find the one key of `T` which is not a key of `Tail<T>`, and index into `T` with that.  You can verify that, for example, `Last<[1, 2, 3]>` is `3`.

```
type Last<T extends readonly any[]> = number extends T['length'] ? T[1e100] : {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Tail<T> ? never : T[K] }[number];
```

Then we'll declare `last()` like this:

```
function last<T extends readonly any[]>(t: T): Last<T>;
function last(t: any[]) {
    return t[t.length - 1];
}
```

Note that the compiler cannot verify that `t[t.length-1]` is of type `Last<T>`, so we need to assert that (here I'm using a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) whose implementation signature is looser than the call signature).

---

Armed with `last()`, we can try your `overload()`:

```
function overload(...args: Arguments) {
    if (args.length === 2) console.log(args[0]);
    if (args.length === 3) console.log(args[0], args[1]);
    last(args)(); // okay
}
```

That works!  If I examine the type of `last(args)`, you'll see what you expected:

```
const f = last(args);
// const f: () => void
```

And if you change the last element of any of the tuples in the `Arguments` union so that it's not a zero-arg function type, the compiler will warn you:

```
function badOverload(...args: Arguments | [string, number, boolean, string]) {
    const f = last(args);
    // const f: string | () => void
    last(args)(); // error! string is not callable
}
```

---

Okay, hope that's useful to you.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-pEQZDZIpEayAGZY-HEzBk6n8xmOMZa3Ss764HHCNE4HMskiwGng82sUIAPRD1vxsCdmTKhSq1wtnt973KgJwEdwWgTJAQBl3C0IgkFGgAeVt9uIjrE+bdHK5hB5cClMrAcvJuvy+uMBVolZYxm15PROBMRzAN81Dclw0jaNy3bStq0XOsBxAvMXXAosoLgMsx1gpM7RrdMegbdMm2zIQ2w7LsPi+RckOHUdyInKwZH-GoH0FGc1Xnaj81kZdV1HWwKFoCgAEI4BYsZyEIWgJyeJA0E+Apqh3W5VNAEdWQJPAkDyKBqnXOYdFoAB3OAAEkKnVNAUCmQlaFbeS0DGMBQBtWw7QdadnGwhNcJTYQAAMLLyZg0GMrdyHqeAewkALZAHNyKA888Km03TqgqYwvJ4ci4LwwKnRIcyKhCpBO0eS16Fi+KbkS5LhFS3AdL0mBMtpLKnByis-NTALJB0JBZJYOAigchSYGIOKB1AIA)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly cast the array item as a `() => void` before calling it. The type check alone isn't enough to alert typescript that the array item is callable.

```
if(typeof args[args.length-1]==='function'){
    (args[args.length - 1] as () => void)();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to achieve something like that:

```js
type Args<T> = [...T[], () => void];

function process<T>(...args: Args<T>) {
    let [...values, func] = args;
    for (let value of values) {
        console.log(value);
    }
    func();
}
```

Unfortunately it's not possible because the rest operator can be applied only to the last element of a tuple type and also must be the last expression in javascript array comprehensions.

Possible workaround is to put a function type as the first element in a tuple:

```js
type Args<T> = [() => void, ...T[]];

function process<T>(...args: Args<T>) {
    let [func, ...values] = args;
    for (let value of values) {
        console.log(value);
    }
    func();
}

process(() => console.log("process"));
process(() => console.log("process"), 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this is not exactly what I meant. I wanted my function to type check only for a specified number of parameters e.g. if the function was called with 2 parameters then `function(...args:[...args:[string,{():void}])` or if with 3 then...or when was called with 5 parameter then it's an error. I'm not sure if I'm not missing the point here...
Side question - is there a reason that you wrote `for(let value of values){}` instead of `for(const value of values){}`?

Comment: `const` just means that the value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not support arguments after a spread syntax. So, this is not allowed:

```js
function run(...args: Array<any>, callback: () => void){}
```

The only workaround is providing overloads without the spread syntax:

```js
function run(a: number, callback: () => void): void;
function run(a: number, b: number, callback: () => void): void;
function run(a: number, b: number, c: string, callback: () => void): void {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Last<T extends any[] | readonly any[]> = T extends [...infer _, infer L] ? L : T extends readonly [...infer _, infer L] ? L : never;
type tup = [1, '2', 3, '4'];
type last = Last<tup>; // '4'
```

Comment: You should improve your answer by explaining it.